# Solutions of $x^{3}+y^{3}=x-y$ with $(x,y) ∈Q$ and rational points on the curve $\epsilon^2+12\eta^4=1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Setting

$y=\frac{1-u}{1+u}x$

$x=(1+u)\sqrt{\frac{u}{1+3u^{2}}}$

$u=u_{k}$

and

$u_{k+1}=\frac{4u_{k}(1+3u_{k}^{2})}{(1-3u_{k}^2)^{2}}$

with

$u_{0}=1.$

If $u_{0}=1$ then $x=0$ and $y=0$

If $u_{1}=4$ then $x=\frac{10}{7}$ and $y=-\frac{6}{7}$;

if $u_{2}=\frac{2^{4}7^{2}}{47^{2}}$

then

$x=\frac{2^{2}. 7. 41.73}{47. 2593}$

$y=\frac{2^{2}.3. 5^{2}. 7. 19}{47. 2593}$

and so on…

If $u:=\frac{1}{3u}$,

we have the same value of u_{k+1} and  the values of $x$ and $y$ are:

$x=\frac{3u+1}{3\sqrt{u}\sqrt{1+3u^{2}}}$

$y=\frac{3u-1}{3\sqrt{u}\sqrt{1+3u^{2}}}$

therefore

If $u_{0}=1$ then $x=\frac{2}{3}$ and $y=-\frac{1}{3}$;

if $u_{1}=4$ then $x=\frac{13}{42}$ and $y=-\frac{11}{42}$;

if $u_{2}=\frac{2^{4}7^{2}}{47^{2}}$ then

$x=\frac{47. 4561}{2^{2}. 3. 7.2593}$

$y=\frac{11. 13. 47}{2^{2}. 3. 7. 2593}$

If $u_{3}=\frac{2^{6}. 7^{2}. 47^{2}. 2593^{2}}{3035713^{2}}$

Then

$x=\frac{13. 228. 3035713. 50033004961}{2^{3}. 3. 7. 31. 47. 2593. 151681. 17268703}$

$y=\frac{11. 4391. 10979.246121. 3035713}{2^{3}. 3. 7. 31. 47. 2593. 151681. 17268703}$.

and so on...

Are there other solutions?

Rational points on the curve

$$\epsilon^2+12\eta^4=1$$

@Sophie – Looking back, you're right! In fact, using my symbolism, to find the points on the curve

$\epsilon^2+12\eta^4=1$

with rational points, 
just set

$\epsilon_{k+1}=\sqrt{1-12\eta_{k}^4}$

and

$\eta_{k+1}=\frac{\sqrt{u_{k}}}{\sqrt{1+3u_{k}^2}}$.

If $u_{0}=1$ then $\eta_{1}=\frac{1}{2}$ and $\epsilon_{1}=\frac{1}{2}$

If $u_{1}=4$ then $\eta_{2}=\frac{2}{7}$ and $\epsilon_{2}=\frac{47}{49}$

If $u_{2}=\frac{2^{4}.7^{2}}{47^{2}}$ then $\eta_{3}=\frac{2^{2}.7.47}{2593}$ and $\epsilon_{3}=\frac{3035713}{2593^{2}}$

and so on…

Comment: By letting  $a=x+y$, $b=x-y$ and solving for b I found that this is equivalent to finding rational points on the curve $x^{2}+12y^{4}=1$. I'm think that should lead to a solution somehow but I haven't been able to finish.

Comment: Birational to https://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/288/a/2